# Struts2 create dropdown dymamically based on first dropdown value in Struts2 using hibernate

Tags: struts2

Hi I am using Struts2 and hibernate now in my jsp I have Two dropdown ,on selection of first drop  it should call a function and retrive the values for second drop down from the database

Please help

Comment: We're no Amazon turks programming stuff for you. What is the question you have or what doesn't work that should work? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have number of options here and some of them are

1. user [struts2-jquery](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) plugin which comes with this feature where you can create two dependable select.
2. user simple jquery with JSON ([struts2 plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)) and use ajax.

i will prefer second approach which is much more flexible.create a custom JS function with help from jquery and when use select first option from drop down call your action methods which will send JSON data based on the selected values and use JQuery build in JSON parsing mechanism to parse the content and fill second drop-down.

a simple Google search will give you a number of results.